model suggestions for managing bids on ad platforms
We manage multiple campaigns on platforms like Google Ads and Trivago for our hotels. Part of our job on weekly basis is to adjust bids so our properties win auctions and be visible to guests. Bid values are adjusted based on properties performance metrics like impressions, clicks, conversions etc.
Currently investigating if any ML models could be applied to adjust the bids automatically based on the data(have almost 4 yrs worth of data). At an initial glance looks this looks like regression problem(bid value being continuous variable between some range) but also thinking reinforcement learning may help too(continually optimising bid values based on positive metrics). Any pointers would be appreiciated.
